# Delay in program like as sleep()

Tags: c#

I have a question about delay in Visual Studio 2010 C sharp.
I need time delay in program for send position to servo. Now I am using   **System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200))** but i need the delay which i can interupt.

When i use the sleep, that program during sleep not work. (on Click button,trackbar move ...), but I must control the program during the delay.

What is exist in VS like as function sleep?

Thank you very much for your reply.

Martin

Comment: When you say "What is exist in VS..." you really mean, "What exists in .NET as Visual Studio is just an IDE, not a language.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, thank you for your repair.

Answer (score 2):

you can work your process in async task without block your app.. and use Task.Delay() (its only block current task)

```
    public async Task SomeWork()
    {
        while (someCondition)
        {
            //do some work
            await Task.Delay(100);//milliseconds
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Task.Delay`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194845(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public void mainFunction() {
  //do stuff here
  var delayTime = 1.5;
  CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
  var t = Task.Run(async delegate
  {
     await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delayTime), source.Token);
     delayableFunction();
  });

  //can cancel here if necessary
  source.Cancel();
  //just continue on with other stuff... 
}

public void delayableFunction() {
  //do delay-able stuff here
}
```

Comment: Think you may have a mixed a few languages there haha. There's no `function` keyword in C#

Answer (score 1):

Use the Async [`Task.Delay()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194845(v=vs.110).aspx) function with a cancellation token

Here's a quick example:

```
bool sendPos = true;

public async Task SomeFunction(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (sendPos)
    {
        SendServoPos();
        await Task.Delay(1000, token)
    }
}

public void MainFunction()
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    // Fire and Forget - Note it will silently throw exceptions
    SomeFunction(tokenSource.Token)

    // Cancel Loop
    sendPos = false;
    tokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using VS2010, you **won't have access to C# 5** features (*async* / *await* keywords) and most probably are limited to .NET 4.0. Unfortunately that version does not have the [Task.Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

If that's the case the easiest option for you may be using either [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.100).aspx) or [System.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdzx8wx8(v=vs.100).aspx) depending on your needs. Both will execute a method on a thread pool thread after a delay. You can stop both of them before a tick and both of them support "infinite" periods.

Stopping the thread timer is not obvious, use [Timer.Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148(v=vs.100).aspx) method for this.

The links above have nice usage examples.